# Bash Error when echo print two number variables

Tags: bash, syntax

Look at this folks

```
r1=$(grep -c "Error_type1" file.txt)

r2=$(grep -c "Error_type2" file.txt)
```

all fine until here, but if I try to print total of errors:

```
echo $r1+$r2
```

> $1+1

```
echo $(r1+r2)
```

> $command not found

```
echo $($r1+$r2)
```

> $command not found

I don´t wanna create a 3rd variable with the sum.
Any ideas?

Comment: You want `$((r1+r2))`. `$(...)` is for executing a command and substituting its output, `$((...))` executes arithmetic.

Comment: You obviously already know that, since you use `$(grep ...)`